# Asyncmongo not return _id

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

Use PyMongo:

```
import pymongo
conn=pymongo.Connection(host='127.0.0.1',port=27017)
db=conn.cms
db.comments.save({'content':'test', 'user':'admin'})
```

Then return:

```
ObjectId('4ea175b96e955237aa000000')
```

That all right with PyMongo.
**But I cannot get _id in response when I use AsyncMongo.**

```
class PoCommentsHandler(BaseClass):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def post(self):
        self.mongo.comments.save({'content':'test', 'user':'admin'}, callback=self._callback)
    def _callback(self, response, error):
        if error: raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500)
        logging.info(response)
        self.finish(str(response))
```

Then return:

```
[I 111021 21:25:02 cms:104] [{u'connectionId': 41, u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'n': 0}]
```

Who can tell me what Wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong, the MongoDB itself does not return id of just inserted document, the **pymongo** does it for you. There is asynchronous implementation of pymongo API (also on Tornado IOLoop) called [APyMongo](https://github.com/govdata/APyMongo), which should behave as you expected.

More on this topic could be found in this google groups thread: http://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/9f43f85916156848